# Which of these sentences is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

I am getting confused with what form of the verb to use:

1. Anyone who knows him, also ***know*** her.
2. Anyone who knows him, also ***knows*** her.

Out of these sentences, which one is correct?

Singular nouns are attached to plural verbs. So, I'm thinking the second sentence is correct.

I'm getting confused because the first one is also *sounding* right!

Comment: ***Anyone*** (like ***everyone***) is ***singular***, [as any fule kno](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/any_fule_kno), so #1 is invalid (unless you're Adrian Mole! :)

Comment: The first one sounds very wrong to me, if that helps.

Comment: Does it? Okay.. That's good to know.. So, I'll stick to the second sentence then. Thanks a lot both of you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is wrong, and your logic is right. Both arms of the connective "also" have the same subject, so the verbs must be in the same form.

[Please don't think of *knows* as a "plural verb": I think I understand why you say this - because it has the -s ending, which is typical of plural nouns in English. But it is very definitely a singular verb.]